# How can i select text with Conemu command tool?

Tags: conemu

How can i select text with Conemu so that I can copy it?

Dragging over it with my mouse (like i do with the CMD mac or terminal in Linux) doesn't work. Note - I don't want the auto copying of text to the clipboard.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, long time ago, but later than 2012 of course, "Intelligent selection mode" was implemented. It's enabled by default.

When you start mouse dragging horizontally the text selection begins, and starting dragging vertically begins vertical/block selection. Easy and no any modifier.

If you do not want to "Copy on Left Button release" just uncheck this option.

All these on the "Mark/Copy" settings page.

[image: ConEmu's Mark/Copy]

Comment: You can select text via `Shift+mouse` nowdays. Version 150813f.

Comment: Wrong sequence. Shift+mouse was implemented far before than Intelligent mode appeared.

Answer (score 0):

ConEmu uses a modifier key to enable text selection.  I believe it's Left Shift by default.

You can see what yours is set to in the settings:

[image]

Comment: Very old build...